# Compile c++ for android/iOS

Tags: android, c++, ios

I have to compile a library (library BPG from [Bellard.org](https://bellard.org/bpg/)) to create a .so or a dll that I can use with android/iOS.

I'm working with Visual Studio. With some researches, I found the project "Visual C++ -> Cross Platform -> Shared Library (Android, iOS)". But I am totally lost and can't do anything.

The downloaded library is organised with some folders but Visual don't allow to make tree, all files are sorted by filters (one for header and one for sources). So I can't build, I have more than 300 errors, "can't open source file", "undefined variable"...

Secondly, the README file from project says :

> The following packages need to be installed: mingw64-gcc mingw64-libpng mingw64-libjpeg-turbo mingw64-SDL mingw64-SDL_image yasm

I found installed for mingw 32 bits but no 64 bits so I don't know if build can perform. I don't know how to find the libraries.

So my question is, what is the best way to compile a C/C++ library for android/iOS ? And where can I find a tutorial for beginners ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I have worked as cross compiling engineer for several years. The most suitable IDE for you I think, is the CLion with CMake inside.

CMake is a tool which can cross-compile the C/C++ library into ios\android\linux\etc.. using only one config file: "CMakeList.txt". 
The main task of CMake is to translate CMakeList.txt to Makefile on every platform and provide you the .a and .so files.

CLion is very powerful IDE in code editing and debugging.

Furthermore, Android needs JNI (or JNA if performance is not concerned) to wrap your c++ interfaces to java classes. Here I would recommend SWIG. SWIG is a tool to wrap C++ interfaces to other languages, that means, not only java on android you can support , other days your lib can also support python\tcl\Go\etc.

Comment: I'll check that. It's my first cross-compile, I'll search for a tutorial about using CLion/CMake and try to compile my library. Hope it'll work, I'm trying to do that for some days but I still have not advanced.

Comment: I passed the day trying to compile the [library](https://bellard.org/bpg/) but I failed. I still have errors like `'transform' undeclared`. I installed all the packages but I don't know why I can't compile.

Comment: i highly recommend letting linux  be your development os . even though it is ok to use windows with mingw .  these years i struggled between all the operating systems , windows\ubuntu\macos, util i found linux centos 7 .  perfect for cross compilers ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Which os are u using to build the lib? macOS or win ?

For iOS : .a  file
For Android: .so file

First you should check the README file

- Edit the Makefile to change the compile options (the default
  compile options should be OK). Type 'make' to compile and 'make
  install' to install the compiled binaries.
- Use 'make -j N' where N is the number of CPU cores to compile faster.
- The following packages must be installed: SDL-devel
  SDL_image-devel yasm. It is recommended to use yasm version >= 1.3.0
  to have a faster compilation.
- Only a 64 bit target is supported because x265 needs it for bit
  depths > 8.

check this to install SDL packages 
https://wiki.libsdl.org/Installation

Comment: I'm using Windows. I already have the SDL packages, but I did not find a way to get the mingw64 packages (like mingw64-libpng)